# Java - creating a folder and file in web server directory

Tags: java, webserver, relative-path

i would like to create a file in a folder (TestFolder) of web server. I will i get relative path of web server directory and how will i create my TestFolder in that directory.

currently i will create a folder in my local server but later i need to create a folder in test environment (server could be different on test environment)

Comment: Please post code showing what you tried, with the errors you got if any, and describing the expected/actual behavior of the code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
String realPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
File file = new FIle(realPath+"/TestFolder", "testFIle.txt");
file.mkdirs();
```

The above code will create a folder `TestFolder` and a file `testFIle.txt` in the root directory of your web application.

`file.mkdirs()` Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories. Note that if this operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the necessary parent directories.

**Returns:**
`true` if and only if the directory was created, along with all necessary parent directories; `false` otherwise

Hope this helps !